# sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation

Tags: ssh, gnome

when I execute `ssh -i`, ubuntu pop up a password input box, I didn't enter the password and I click the checkbox on the box and click the unlock button.
After that, the password box won't pop up again and I can never execute ssh successfully.
Then I run `ssh-add -l`:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rstV9.png)

There is a line generated which is related with my ssh credentials.
So I want to delete it, I run `ssh-add -D` but it did't make sense.
How can I delete the line from `ssh-add -l` and make the password input box pop up again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to fix this problem! 
In ubuntu 18.04, we can access "Passwords and Keys" -> "Passwods" or "Secure Shell" (where is your password stored in). Then delete this entry. The password input box will pop up again.

Comment: wow, that deleted my id_rsa. Im glad I took a backup first!